# retrieving data from a website

Tags: javascript, xml

I need to get some information from a website using javascript.

https://xml.buienradar.nl/

I need to get this information from this website. I hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is get this xml and extract information from it you should be interested in way of parsing xml into javascript objects. You could read about it on [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp). There are lot of informations about way of handling data. To get this information to "load" to your variables you have to get interested in a ways of making HTTP GET on this URL.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code snippet into your html file, open that html file in chrome, open developer tool (inspect) then check console tab to see loaded xml.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">    
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
      console.log(xmlDoc);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://xml.buienradar.nl/", true);
  xhttp.send(null);
</script>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you resolve your question, please mark it with